# Google Maps Web site and API : different results

Tags: api, google-maps, geolocation, request

Why do calls to the Google Maps Geocoder API return different results than what I see in my browser?

This one returns many items :
http://maps.google.fr/maps?q=McDonald,+paris

This one returns a ZERO_RESULT :
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?McDonald,+paris&sensor=false

Answer (score 12, accepted):

FAQ: https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#geocoder_differences

The API geocoder finds **postal addresses**. The Maps geocoder uses lots of data, including business data, to find results.

There is the Places API which can find locations based on *type/class*, but it may not work for business *names*. [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/)

Comment: Reading the doc, I don't see where you saw that it may not work for business names ? Can you point the sentence please ?

Comment: @Oliver: It's experimental and still being developed, so it may well be buggy. From other reports, *Types* seem to work ok. The documentation says "*keyword* — A term to be matched against all content that Google has indexed for this Place, including but not limited to name, type, and address, as well as customer reviews and other third-party content," so that may well be ok too. I just didn't want to say that it definitely would be! Give it a go and report back: the information will be useful for others.

Comment: Is there a way to access the Maps geocoder mentioned in this answer?

Comment: Reviewing the documentation I linked to in my answer, it appears the [Places JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/places/javascript) now uses the same database as Google Maps and Google+ Local.