# Google directions api changes destination address

Tags: google-maps, directions, google-directions-api

Can someone explain why the destination address I entered in the source code is not the same as the end location on this page?

http://talextech.net/test_map.php

If I input the origin and destination on Google's directions page they work fine.

Comment: Try to avoid making people leave SO: add your code, the actual result, and the result you expected.

Answer (score 0):

"ITC, Senator Gil Puyat Ave, Lungsod ng Makati, Philippines" is not a valid address.  Google Maps uses its Places database (and search results) to locate the [ITC building](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=ITC,+Senator+Gil+Puyat+Ave,+Lungsod+ng+Makati,+Philippines&hl=en&ll=14.618136,121.047363&spn=0.397985,0.441513&sll=32.824552,-117.108978&sspn=0.691256,0.883026&hq=ITC,&hnear=Ayala+Ave,+Lungsod+ng+Makati,+Metro+Manila,+Philippines&t=m&z=11&iwloc=B), which appears to be at:

> International Trade Centrer 
>   Senator Gil Puyat Avenue 1200 
>   Philippines

Answer (score 0):

Basically there is a difference in name and address. Google database can have other symbols for the same location. You can read  my answer here: http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/12788664/google-maps-api-geocode-returns-different-co-ordinates-then-google-maps/12790012#12790012. In the google response the name is what you are looking for and in the placemark object the list of address and location in the google database. You need to loop through the placemark object to find the most similar location.