# Google Maps Geocoder returning the same results

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding, google-geocoder

I am using Google Maps API Geocoder to geocode an address.

**Problem:** When the server does the geocoding, I often (not always) get results that have the **exact same** lat/lng, and this is the lat/lng of the city center.

However when I call the exact same URL on my browser, I always get the correct lat/lng returned!

Any idea why its returning the wrong and different results when the same URL is called from server and from my browser?

**Query URL**

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=6954 N Greenview, Chicago, IL&sensor=false&region=us
```

**Results on Server** *(Using curl)*

```
"lat": 41.8781136
"lng": -87.6297982
```

**Results on Browser**

```
"lat" : 42.0082060,
"lng" : -87.66836499999999
```

Comment: See this [Region Biasing](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/index).

Comment: Thanks, I believe that I'm biasing the region to `us`. I've appended `&region=us` to the end of the query url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also believe it's region bias but did you tried comparing name and address of the result? It's happen to me sometimes I get the address and not the name lat lng pairs. I suggest you also to try this url from google http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q= see my answer: [Google Maps API: Geocode returns different co-ordinates then Google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12788664/google-maps-api-geocode-returns-different-co-ordinates-then-google-maps/12790012#12790012).

Comment: What is the difference between using `http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=` and using `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?`? Is the first one from Google Maps API v2?

Comment: Yes, it's from the api v2 and also the mime type is different. You can get see the result in the browser.