# Google Map geocoder not as accurate as a Google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I have a database containing addresses that are accurate to building level. When I put these manually into Google Map's search, Google Maps finds them no problem - the markers appears right over the correct building. However, when I pass these same addresses to the Google Maps API geocoder using the below code, the markers show up only on the street and not the building.

How do I increase the accuracy?

HTML/PHP:

```
<div id="addressline"><?php echo theaddress(); ?></div>
```

JS:

```
      function myGeocodeFirst() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        geocoder.geocode( {'address': document.getElementById("addressline").innerHTML},
          function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
              firstLoc = results[0].geometry.location;
              map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
              {
                center: firstLoc,
                zoom: 15,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
              });
              markers = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: firstLoc,
              map: map,
        });

            } 
            else {
              document.getElementById("text_status").value = status;
            }
          }
        );
      }
window.onload=myGeocodeFirst;
```

Comment: If you already have the correct location, why are you using the geocoder?  Are you sure the locations that Google Maps is reporting aren't entries from the Places database, rather than the geocoder?  Can you provide examples?

Comment: I don't have the latitute/longitude, just the address in the form: 123 Road, City, P05T C0D3

Comment: Do you have an example address that shows the problem?

Comment: Yes, this is a church. It shows up fine in Google Maps, but the API points to a nearby spot close to the road: St Clement’s Church, Edge Lane, Chorlton, M21 9JF

Answer (score 3):

Google Maps uses a number of different data sources to locate search results on the map.

The entry you are seeing that is "correct" is a Places database entry.  See [this page](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_places-searchboxB.html) and enter you search string (St Clement’s Church, Edge Lane, Chorlton, M21 9JF).

The geocoder gets is designed to return coordinates for postal addresses, there is not enough information in your string for it to return accurate results:

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=St%20Clement%E2%80%99s%20Church,%20Edge%20Lane,%20Chorlton,%20M21%209JF&geocode=1

It looks like it is just returning the geocode for the postcode:

```
Manchester M21 9JF, UK (53.4414411, -2.285287100000005)
```

It does look like the geocoder does have that location in it.  If I use "St Clement’s Church, Edge Lane", it seems to get the "rooftop" geocode (although it reports "APPROXIMATE")

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=St%20Clement%E2%80%99s%20Church,%20Edge%20Lane,%20Chorlton,%20M21%209JF&geocode=1&addr2=St%20Clement%E2%80%99s%20Church,%20Edge%20Lane&geocode=2

```
St Clement's Church, 6 Edge Ln, Manchester, Lancashire M21 9JF, UK (53.4406823, -2.283755499999984)
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/Lf1yghwj/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder, map, service, infowindow, bounds;

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var request = {
    query: "St Clement’s Church, Edge Lane, Chorlton, M21 9JF"
  }
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  service.textSearch(request, callback);

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      var place = results[i];
      var marker = createMarker(results[i]);
      bounds.extend(marker.getPosition())
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');
  }
}

function createMarker(place) {
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(place.name);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
  });
  return marker;
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Ok thanks looks like all my addresses are partial. Is there a way to get more accurate results in Google Maps API with partial addresses? I have build number/name, city/area and postcode mostly

Comment: You can try seeing if the Places API works better than the geocoder with your data.

Comment: How can we use Places Api with gecoder data?@geocodezip

Comment: added example with the places API.

Answer (score 1):

Basically there is a name and an address. Google database can have other name for the same location. You can read my answer here: http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/12788664/google-maps-api-geocode-returns-different-co-ordinates-then-google-maps/12790012#12790012. In the google response you need to loop through the placemark object to find the most similar location.