# google geocoding api not as accurate as google maps using address

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding, google-geocoding-api

I have many examples where google maps returns the exact location whereas geocoding cannot find an exact match and provides only a close match lat/lon which is no good for my purpose.

example: "1729 state road 8, auburn, IN 46706" in google maps drops me exactly on a walmart distribution center as it should.

using geocoding.....either thru 
http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geocoder/singlegeocode.html

or manually

via https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1729+state+road+8,+auburn,+IN,+46706&key=[your_key_here]

has the location several miles away...

I don't understand why the difference as I would expact MAPs to use geocoding etc, and many many examples don't match up between the two. I need to get geocoding via MAPS !

Comment: Similar question [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13312680/google-map-geocoder-not-as-accurate-as-a-google-maps/13313663#13313663).  The suggestion there is that you might get better results with the Places API or library than with geocoding.

Answer (score 3):

After reading through lot of answers i came across this solution that **Gecoder** is used to find the nearest postal addresses.To get Local Business Data use Google Places API

> https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests

it can be done like this

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=someplacename&key=key
```