# pygeocoder returning wrong geocode

Tags: python, python-3.x

Many times it's returning result within around 1.0 miles but not exact.

```
from pygeocoder import Geocoder
addr = "Hometown BI-LO, 1016 Pine Log Road, Aiken, SC 29803, United States"
Geocoder.geocode(addr)[0].coordinates
```

returns (33.516093, -81.73750240000001)

When same i searched on google map site it's showing 1 mile far.

My client gives me address and i convert them into geocodes.

I have also tried with geocode api.

[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=BI-LO+HOMETOWN,+1016+PINE+LOG+ROAD,+AIKEN,+SC+29803][1]

My client gives me address and i convert them into geocodes.

**Is there any way searching on google map site and using script always return same result?**

Answer (score 0):

You could have a try with this library:

http://geocoder.readthedocs.org/en/latest/providers/Google/

It is an active open source project. You could ask help if you don't get the result you want and the best part of open source: you can fork and create a pull request.

Comment: It return 5.0 miles away.

`g = geocoder.mapquest('Hometown BI-LO, Hometown BI-LO, 1016 Pine Log Road, Aiken, SC 29803, United States')`

`g.lat, g.lng`

Comment: Did you try with the google provider? Because your command is for mapquest. If you want same result as Google map, you should use google provider

Comment: Yes, even with google provider not geeting correct output.
`g = geocoder.google('Hometown BI-LO, Hometown BI-LO, 1016 Pine Log Road, Aiken, SC 29803, United States')`

`g.latlng`
[33.516093, -81.73750240000001]

**Expected [33.523116, -81.724922]** @SBiilion

Comment: Ok. I didn't understand that your problem was with the google map api.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10567487/google-maps-web-site-and-api-different-results