# geocode result different from google maps

Tags: r, google-maps, geocode, ggmap

I'm trying to geocode different IATA airport codes in Italy, with the following (rudimentary) code in `ggmap` (version 2.4)

```
#list of all IATA codes
geo_apt <- c("AOI", "BGY", "BLQ", "BRI", "CTA", "FCO", "LIN", "MXP", "NAP", 
"PMF", "PSA", "PSR", "RMI", "TRN", "VCE", "VRN")

#preparing an empty dataframe to store the geocodes
apt_geo <- data.frame(IATA=rep(NA,16), lon=rep(NA,16), lat=rep(NA,16))

#geocoding the codes
for (i in seq_along(geo_apt)) {
  apt_geo[i,1] <- geo_apt[i]
  apt_geo[i,2] <- (geocode(paste(geo_apt[i],"airport")))[1]
  apt_geo[i,3] <- (geocode(paste(geo_apt[i],"airport")))[2]
}
```

and the `geocode` function of `ggmap` works perfectly fine with all of these codes except "PSR"

```
   IATA        lon      lat
1   AOI  13.363752 43.61654
2   BGY   9.703631 45.66957
3   BLQ  11.287859 44.53452
4   BRI  16.765202 41.13751
5   CTA  15.065775 37.46730
6   FCO  12.246238 41.79989
7   LIN   9.276308 45.45218
8   MXP   8.725531 45.63006
9   NAP  14.286579 40.88299
10  PMF  10.295935 44.82326
11  PSA  10.397884 43.68908
12  PSR -81.117259 33.94855  #<- doens't work
13  RMI  12.618819 44.02289
14  TRN   7.647867 45.19654
15  VCE  12.339771 45.50506
16  VRN  10.890141 45.40000
```

I've tried to use `revgeocode` and those coordinates correspond to the following address:

```
revgeocode(as.numeric(apt_geo[12,2:3]))
#Information from URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=33.948545,-81.1172588&sensor=false
[1] "Kentucky Avenue, West Columbia, SC 29170, USA"
```

On the contrary, if I go to Google maps, it works perfectly fine:

[image: map of Pescara airport]

Does anybody have a clue on this apparently strange phenomenon?

**EDIT**

Following one suggestion in the comments below, I tried to use `geocode(italy PSR airport)` on version 2.4 again and instead of throwing a more accurate result or even the same result, this is the warning I got:

```
geocode("italy PSR airport")
  lon lat
1  NA  NA
Warning message:
geocode failed with status ZERO_RESULTS, location = "italy PSR airport"
```

while with the attempt `airport PSR` the coordinates are even different from those of `PSR airport` (at least this time it's an actual airport, although its IATA code is LEX instead of PSR).

```
revgeocode(as.numeric(geocode("airport PSR")))
Information from URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=38.0381454,-84.5970727&sensor=false
[1] "3895 Terminal Drive, Lexington, KY 40510, USA"
```

Comment: With `ggmap` version 2.5, using `geocode("italy PSR airport")`, you get `12.8333 42.8333`. But `revgeocode` shows it is not correct.

Comment: @Pascal how did you install ggmap version 2.5? I have a 2.4 version, and if I try to do `geocode("italy PSR airport")`
Warning message:
geocode failed with status ZERO_RESULTS, location = "italy PSR airport" `

Comment: Here: https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap#installation

Comment: Maybe the API doesn't offer the full data that Google Maps uses? Anyway, `gc <- geocode("Pescara Airport"); revgeocode(unlist(gc[1, ])); # "Abruzzo Airport, Via Tiburtina, Km 229,100, 65131 Pescara PE, Italy"` - I'd suggest decoding the airport IATAs beforehand using e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_airports_in_Italy

Comment: @lukeA I suspect as well that the API isn't complete. I knew that with "Pescara airport" it worked, and I know what is what in that list (e.g. AOI stands for Ancona, RMI for Rimini, and so on) but I would rather avoid this solution... my question was more related with the reason of these strange mismatches (as far as I can see, I'm not the only one reporting strange `geocode` results)

Answer (score 0):

The whole question is a possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10567487/google-maps-web-site-and-api-different-results)

Nonetheless, I don't get the reason for which the API and Google maps are using different datasets...